# Formatação decimal para PT-BR no Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Usando o pipe **DecimalPipe** estou tentando colocar a formatação numérica para pt-BR, exemplo: *1.200,00*.

Por default o Angular utiliza a formatação en-US, exemplo: *1,200.00*.

Visto na lista da [ISO](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php) a formatação para o português correta seria '**pt**'.

Na [doc](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) do **DecimalPipe** consta a seguinte sintaxe para conseguir essa formatação:

```
// app.component.ts file
export class NumberPipeComponent {
  pi: number = 3.14159265359;
}

// app.component.html file
    <p>
      With digitsInfo and
      locale parameters specified:
      {{pi | number:'4.1-5':'pt'}}
      <!--output: '0 003,14159'-->
    </p>
```

Tentei aplicar a sintaxe acima no que me retorna o seguinte erro:

> ERROR Error: NG02100: InvalidPipeArgument: 'NG0701: Missing locale data for the locale "pt".' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'

Apesar da lista da ISO informar que o padrão seria o 'pt', encontrei em diversos fóruns alternativas para incluir como: **pt-PT e pt-BR** porém todas me retornam o mesmo erro.

Na documentação do [LOCALE_ID](https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID) informa para importar o LOCAL_ID no appModule do projeto e prover a formatação, desta forma:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt' }]
});
```

Tentei aplicar da maneira acima e continua o mesmo erro:

> ERROR Error: NG02100: InvalidPipeArgument: 'NG0701: Missing locale data for the locale "pt".' for pipe 'DecimalPipe'

Não encontrei outra forma em que eu poderia resolver este erro para o **locale**, alguma sugestão?

Comment: Não entendi bem a pergunta, se vc está tentando formatar um número para um valor **monetário** pq está utilizando o `pipe number`, não deveria utilizar o **`currency`**: https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe?

Comment: Utilizei valor monetario apenas como exemplo, o foco seria para o formato em si 1.200,00 = BR e 1,200.00 = US. Porém mesmo com o currency a formatação continua com a virgula na frente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por padrão, o Angular contém apenas dados de localidade para en-US. Se você definir o valor de LOCALE_ID para outro código de idioma, deverá importar dados de código de idioma para esse novo código de idioma.

segue um exemplo de como configurar:

```
import { DecimalPipe, registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';

registerLocaleData(localePt);

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt' }
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Você pode encontrar mais detalhes na documentação especifica sobre
[Angular Internationalization](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview#i18n-pipes), [registerLocaleData](https://angular.io/api/common/registerLocaleData).

Comment: Fiz os testes aqui e funcionou, muito obrigado. Agradeço também pela documentação.